# Flutter list custom search with tags

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to make custom search Flutter list

**AAA 00001-01**

1. AAA without anything is definition.
2. AAA 00001 is main value,
3. AAA 00001-01 main value + additional tag, where every value can have additional tab. The list is big ~20k and adding to every value tag is too slow. Tags are always in format -00 and can bee [-00, -10]

Users prefer searches: AAA or AAA 00001 or AAA 00001-01 or 00001

```
    onChanged: (text) {
        text = text.toLowerCase();
        var _text1 =[];
        bool _isNumeric(String str) {
          if(str == null) {
            return false;
          }
          return double.tryParse(str) != null;
        }
        if (_isNumeric(text)){  //check 00001 search
          _text1 = ['', text];
        } else if (text.contains(' ') && text.length > 2) {
          _text1 = text.split(' ');
        } else if (text.contains(new RegExp(r"\-\d\d"))) {
        _fmi = ??;
        }
        setState(() {
          _notesForDisplay = _notes.where((note) {
            var noteTitle = note.code.toLowerCase();
             var noteKey = note.key.toLowerCase();
             var noteFmi = _fmi
            return noteTitle.contains(_text1[0]) && noteKey.contains(_text1[1]) && noteFmi.contains(_fmi);
          }).toList();
      });
```

Any idea how to append tag if user add this in search?

Comment: For such a big one list with ~20k you should use for loop indexed or while loop. Where method filter are slower.

Comment: And why you need convert text to number when you search for string? Just use if contain text return. Sort list, it will find faster all text where starts with AAA to example

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need to add value `_text1.add(text);` then the tag will always be at the end of the list `_text1` and will be easier to connect to the string

Comment: This all works well, but I don't have that extra tag. Sometimes users search for both the first and second value, and sometimes only the second value. The second value is a bit specific, it always starts with 0, some users use it, some do not, so this search is quite satisfactory. What I have no idea about is how to give -01 to a no-entry result for each field of the list.

Comment: Yes, I need add additional info if tag entered in the search. Example: AAA 00001 = some electronic part problem, AAA 00001-01 = some electronic part problem connection problem. Where -01 = connection problem, AAA 00002-01 = some electronic part2 problem connection problem. (Where -01 = connection problem)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not exactly what you want. But here is a more flexible `String` matching function with `RegExp` grouping matching. `RegExp` patterns you can correct to your preferences.

```dart
void main() {
  onChanged('AAA 00001-01');
}

// This not allow tabs convert to integer. Ex: -01 to -1.
String tabToString(num e) => '$e'.length > 2 ? '$e' : '-0${e.abs()}';
final tabs = [-00, -01, -02, -03, -04, -05, -10].map(tabToString);

void onChanged(String text) {
  final exp = RegExp(r'(A+)|(0\d+)|(-\d\d)');
  String? group = exp.stringMatch(text)?.toLowerCase();
  String? group1 = RegExp(r'A+').stringMatch(text)?.toLowerCase();
  String? group2 = RegExp(r'0\d*').stringMatch(text);
  String? group3 = RegExp(r'-\d\d').stringMatch(text);
  // If tab number exist in the list returns tab as String otherwise empty String.
  String tab = tabs.firstWhere((e) => e == group3, orElse: () => '');

  // Always returns the first matching group or null.
  // 
  // This match is good for the search engines
  // if users start to write with tag return tag or `null`
  // if users start to write with 000 return directly 000... or `null`
  // if users start to write with A return a or `null`.
  //
  // Usage: if(group != null) search(group) else return;
  print(group); // aaa <- the firs group from the `String`.
  
  // Returns the first group or null.
  print(group1); // aaa
  
  // Returns the second group or null.
  print(group2); // 00001
  
  // Returns the third group or null.
  print(group3); // -01
  
  // Do what you want with groups.
  String fullMatch = '${group1 ?? ''} ${group2 ?? ''}$tab'.trim();
  print(fullMatch); // aaa 00001-01
}
```

#### Update

For a better string filtering add to your data class add a full code string getter.

```dart
String get fullCode => '${code.toLowerCase()} $key';
```

then filter it.

```dart
String code = '${group1 ?? ''} ${group2 ?? ''}'.trim();
notes.where((note) => note.fullCode.contains(code).toList();
```

Comment: This is ok, but it still gives me the answer on how to add a tag, except to write in the list for each value. 20k x 11tags. I thought there was a way to define a special list of tags, then filter_list1(group1&&gruop2) && filter_list2(group3) -> print(filter_list1+filter_list2)

Comment: I don't really understand you with my English without more examples, from where you search and what you search. But I thought you can combine groups to get the final result. Combine them and filter in your source.

Comment: The example is a bit specific I may not have explained it well. We have a main list defined by group1 && group2. Group3 is just a little extra information (10 values - fixed size) to add to the main list if and only if user type this, after main search. Group3 only makes sense if it is added to the main search. (no signal, low signal, high signal ...)

Comment: Example: AAA = control computer, 00001 = temperature sensor, 00002 = voltage,  ...
Search: AAA 00001 = control computer temperature sensor, AAA 00001-01 = control computer temperature sensor - value too high, AAA 00002 - control computer voltage, AAA 00002-01 = control computer voltage - value too high.
(where -01 = value too high)

Comment: Have you tried my example? In my example `fullMatch` `String` represent the final search object based on the search text. The tag (-01) will be added only if matching the user input. Just play with my example in the DartPad and you will see.

Comment: In short, the `fullMach` `String` automatically generates your search object.

Comment: I think your problem is that the Dart language converts integers ex: -01 to -1 and you can't filter your tabs list with the given 'String`. Look at my updated example.

Comment: Thx. I think this will work. What bothers me is how to present the search results. I think he will be able to appear from two lists. `return noteTitle.contains(group1) && noteKey.contains(group2) && fmiList.contains(group3);`

Comment: It depends on how you want to represent the search list. If you want to show all element that starts with the key then you filter with keys if the user starts writing with code, filter the list with code. By using operator && in your filter you search after only one value. Instead of `&&` use `||`  to show all available notes in the list with user input.

Comment: And use getters in you Note class for better experience. Look at example.

Comment: Thank you so much, I used part of your code and made custom search. I have a small bugs, so when I fix them, I'll post them here.

Comment: It's nice to hear that things are going in the right direction :)